# SQL Server not executing update query inside if statement brackets

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I working on academic attendance monitoring project using Microsoft SQL 2012 express edition, and here I'm sharing with you a strange situation I faced today and couldn't figure it out! hoping for your help.

Please note upper part of procedure is working perfect till it came to updating `@final_result` SQL just ignoring the bracts !!.

for a workaround I've already tried the following:

- putting update queries outside the 'if statement' brackets and it worked fine!! **then why it does not work inside the 'if statement' brackets?**
- using update query with 'case statement' but it didn't work!
- creating different variables for update queries use only (I know it doesn't make sense! But anyhow I don't know what is the issue)

I have posted my entire procedure for your review, I hope it is not a small mistake because I've already spent so much time on this.

```
declare @class_id int = null,
        @badge varchar(8) = null,
        @name varchar(100) = null,
        @enrollment_id int = null,
        @absence_date datetime = null

set @absence_date = '2015-11-4'
set @badge = '100100'
set @class_id = 1039

BEGIN
     Declare @Period1 bit = null,
             @Period2 bit = null,
             @Period3 bit = null,
             @Period4 bit = null,
             @Period5 bit = null,
             @Period6 bit = null,
             @Period7 bit = null,
             @Period8 bit = null, 
             @remarks varchar(100) = null,
             @show_Period1 bit = null,
             @show_Period2 bit = null,
             @show_Period3 bit = null,
             @show_Period4 bit = null,
             @show_Period5 bit = null,
             @show_Period6 bit = null,
             @show_Period7 bit = null,
             @show_Period8 bit = null

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @final_result table(Student_Badge varchar(8), Full_Name varchar(100), Enrollment_id int
        , Period1 bit, Period2 bit, Period3 bit, Period4 bit, Period5 bit, Period6 bit
        , Period7 bit, Period8 bit, Remarks varchar(100))

select A.Student_badge, B.Full_Name, A.Enrollment_id into #tempStudent from tb_Enrollments as A
left outer join tb_Students as B on A.Student_badge=B.Student_Badge where A.Class_id=@class_id and A.Active=1

while (Select count(*) from #tempStudent) > 0
BEGIN
    Select top 1 @badge=Student_badge,@name=Full_Name,@enrollment_id=Enrollment_id from #tempStudent
    if ( (select count(*) from tb_Absence as A left outer join tb_Enrollments as B on A.Enrollment_ID=B.Enrollment_id
          where A.Absence_date=@absence_Date and A.Student_Badge=@badge and B.Class_id=@class_id) > 0) 
        BEGIN
            -- if there is absence record for this student
            Select @Period1=A.Period1, @Period2=A.Period2, @Period3=A.Period3, @Period4=A.Period4, 
                   @Period5=A.Period5, @Period6=A.Period6, @Period7=A.Period7, @Period8=A.Period8, @remarks=A.Remarks 
                   from tb_Absence as A left outer join tb_Enrollments as B on A.Enrollment_ID=B.Enrollment_id
                   where A.Absence_date=@absence_Date and A.Student_Badge=@badge and B.Class_id=@class_id 
                   and A.Enrollment_ID=@enrollment_id
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- if there is no absence record for this student
            Set @Period1 = 0 set @Period2 = 0 set @Period3 = 0 set @Period4 = 0
            set @Period5 = 0 set @Period6 = 0 set @Period7 = 0 set @Period8 = 0 set @remarks = ''
        END

    insert into @final_result values(@badge,@name,@enrollment_id,@Period1,@Period2,@Period3,@Period4
                                    ,@Period5,@Period6,@Period7,@Period8,@remarks)
    delete #tempStudent where Student_badge=@badge
END
drop table #tempStudent

class_id,Period1,Period2,Period3,Period4,Period5,Period6,Period7,Period8
into #tempclasses from tb_Classes where Class_ID=@class_id and active=1

Select @show_Period1=Period1, @show_Period2=Period2, @show_Period3=Period3, @show_Period4=Period4, 
       @show_Period5=Period5, @show_Period6=Period6, @show_Period7=Period7, @show_Period8=Period8 from #tempclasses

-- issue started from here !!
if @show_Period1 = 0
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period1 = 0 
END

if @show_Period2 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period2 = 0 
END

if @show_Period3 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period3 = 0 
END

if @show_Period4 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period4 = 0 
END

if @show_Period5 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period5 = 0 
END

if @show_Period6 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period6 = 0 
END

if @show_Period7 = 0 
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period7 = 0 
END

if (@show_Period8 = 0)
BEGIN 
    update @final_result set Period8 = 0 
END

drop table #tempclasses
select * from @final_result
END
```

Comment: `Select Period1, Period2, Period3, Period4, 
       Period5, Period6,Period7, Period8 from #tempclasses
`. Probably every period is different than 0. Share the result of above select

Comment: I also don't like the loop. You should ask new question with http://sqlfiddle.com sample and you will get set based solution

Comment: You have an invalid statement after `drop table #tempStudent`.  Otherwise, I agree with @lad2025.  You've written this like you're writing C or JavaScript.  SQL works infinitely better when you write it using sets.